# Trying to run a file from php with spaces in path with no success

Tags: php

I'm trying to run the following script in php when i press a button and its not working because of the spaces of the path .

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['RunApp']))
    {
        $Progrpath = "c:\\program files (x86)\\Folder\\app.exe";
        
        exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c $Progrpath");
    }
?>
```

if i write instead
$Progrpath = "c:\windows\notepad.exe it runs normally. Any help ?

Comment: I always like to mention [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) which, if you are on PHP 7.4 or greater, and you pass an array to it, it will take care of escaping things for you automatically

Answer (score 1):

it was as simple as this. double quote... but i was putting them versa versa ("'...url '") :) and it was not working .... problem solved ! Thanks Chris !

Correct one for anyone searches is :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['RunApp']))
    {
        $Progrpath = '"c:\\program files (x86)\\Folder\\app.exe"';
        
        exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c $Progrpath");
    }
?>
```